# Extracting column names from a dataframe based on condition on row value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
     A     B     C
 u1  0     .5    .2
 u2  .2     0     .3
 u3   .1    0     0
```

I need to find column names against each index where values is not zero
So i need output

```
        elements 
    u1  [B,C]
    u2  [A,C]
    u3  [A]
```

I can find column name of top value across rows using `df.idxmax(axis=1)`
but how to find all names of column.

Comment: Probably worth specifying what kind of DataFrame you have.. `spark` , `pandas`  ?

Comment: Solution does not work? There is some problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for process by rows and filter by convert values to `bool` - `0` is `False`, not `0` is `True`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.astype(bool)].tolist(), 1)
print (df)
u1    [B, C]
u2    [A, C]
u3       [A]
dtype: object
```

If output should be `string`s:

```
s = np.where(df, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
df = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (df)
u1    B, C
u2    A, C
u3       A
dtype: object
```

Detail:

```
print (s)
[['' 'B, ' 'C, ']
 ['A, ' '' 'C, ']
 ['A, ' '' '']]
```

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.dtypes)` ? So you use first or second solution?

Comment: df.dtypes are float.

Comment: And need first or second solution?

Comment: I think there is some problem with data, if not confidental can you send me real data to my email in my profile?

Comment: Sure.. I have sent a snapshot

Comment: mudgil.seema@gmail.com

Comment: I get it, give me a sec. Do you use first or second solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157700/discussion-between-seema-mudgil-and-jezrael).

Comment: Could u please checkmail.. I have sent a query

Comment: @jezrael If you wanted to do a lookup based on specific string, as oppose to true vs false, how would you re-write the above code? For instance, if we assume all the values in the above dataframe are in string, I want to print column names for rows that contain "0.2", which would be Column C and Column A for u1 and u2, respectively

Comment: How to do it in a pyspark dataframe ? is there any analogy ?